# csvファイルをPythonで特定の列だけを抽出して、さらに抽出した列の中で特定の列だけセル結合したい

Tags: python, csv

1枚目の写真のcsvファイルであれば「メールアドレス」「姓」「名」「住所」だけを抽出して、さらに2枚目の写真のように「姓」と「名」の列のセルを結合して表示させたいと思っています。
写真では2行ですがもっと増えていくので、行が増えればcsvファイルで自動で特定の列を抽出して、特定のセルも結合して表示させる方法を教えていただきたいです。

[image: 変更前]

[image: 変更後]

Comment: 前の質問でもコメント等で指摘されていましたが、入力も主力もCSVファイルとして処理するなら、Excelで表示するのはやめておいた方が良いでしょう。結果の内容は質問に提示されたExcelのようにはなりません。結果が`B`と`C`の列にまたがるのではなく、`姓名`が`B`に、`住所`が`C`になるはずです。

Comment: そうなんですね。BとCで別々になるということは知りませんでした。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

Polarsライブラリー使う方法

```py
import polars as pl
import io
csv_file = io.StringIO('''
メール,姓,名,出身地,住所
a@example.com,tanaka,taro,北海道,東京都1-1-1
b@example.com,sato,hanako,大阪府,神奈川県1-1-2
c@example.com,takahasi,jiro,大阪府,千葉県1-1-3
d@example.com,cat,tama,,埼玉県1-1-4
e@example.com,dog,pochi,,茨城県1-1-5
''')

df = pl.read_csv(csv_file)
df.select([
    'メール',
    (pl.col('姓') +' ' +pl.col('名')).alias('姓名'),
    '住所',
]).write_csv()

# メール,姓名,住所
# a@example.com,tanaka taro,東京都1-1-1
# b@example.com,sato hanako,神奈川県1-1-2
# c@example.com,takahasi jiro,千葉県1-1-3
# d@example.com,cat tama,埼玉県1-1-4
# e@example.com,dog pochi,茨城県1-1-5
```

Comment: 返信遅くなり申し訳ありません。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

標準モジュールの[csv](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html)から、[DictReader](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)と[DictWriter](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter)を使う方法です。

**サンプルコード**

```
import csv

# 元ファイルのサンプルファイルを作る場合は"""～"""を下準備として実行する
""" 
def create_sample_csv():
    with open("source.csv", "w") as f:
        f.write('''メール,姓,名,出身地,住所
a@example.com,tanaka,taro,北海道,東京都1-1-1
b@example.com,sato,hanako,大阪府,神奈川県1-1-2
c@example.com,takahasi,jiro,大阪府,千葉県1-1-3
d@example.com,cat,tama,,埼玉県1-1-4
e@example.com,dog,pochi,,茨城県1-1-5
''')

create_sample_csv()
""" 

# source.csvを読み込んで、必要な列を整形して辞書型のリストに変換する
dicts = [] # 辞書型のリスト
with open("source.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        # 辞書型の行データ
        dict = {"メール": row["メール"],
                "姓名": row["姓"] + " " + row["名"],
                "住所": row["住所"]}
        dicts.append(dict)

# 辞書型のリストを元にresult.csvを出力
with open("result.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, dict.keys(), lineterminator='\n')
    writer.writeheader() # ヘッダ出力
    writer.writerows(dicts) # 行データ出力
```

Comment: 返信遅くなり申し訳ありません。できました！ありがとうございます！！